# Want to clear shapes in a certain range but there is application error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, shapes

Basically I'm doing a code whereby it would display shapes according to a certain variable. However, once that certain variable changes, there would be "Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error". I wanted to create a module to assign a macro to a button; Want to clear shapes in a certain range but there is error. However, once I reset and debug the module, it works fine. Despite that, the problem arise again if a certain variable changes.

```
Sub ClearingofButton()
Dim pic As Picture
Dim shp As Shape

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

If Sheets("Calculator").Range("AU64").Formula = "5" Then
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
    For Each shp In Sheets("Calculator").Shapes
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        If Not Application.Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("Illustration")) Is Nothing Then
            shp.Delete
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
        End If

    Next shp

    End If
End If

If Sheets("Calculator").Range("AU64").Formula = "10" Then
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
    For Each shp In Sheets("Calculator").Shapes
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        If Not Application.Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("Illustration")) Is Nothing Then
            shp.Delete
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
        End If

    Next shp

    End If
End If

If Sheets("Calculator").Range("AU64").Formula = "19" Then
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
    For Each shp In Sheets("Calculator").Shapes
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        If Not Application.Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("Illustration")) Is Nothing Then
            shp.Delete
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
        End If

    Next shp

    End If
End If

If Sheets("Calculator").Range("AU64").Formula = "30" Then
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
    For Each shp In Sheets("Calculator").Shapes
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        If Not Application.Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("Illustration")) Is Nothing Then
            shp.Delete
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
        End If

    Next shp

    End If
End If

If Sheets("Calculator").Range("AU64").Formula = "40" Then
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
    For Each shp In Sheets("Calculator").Shapes
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        If Not Application.Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("Illustration")) Is Nothing Then
            shp.Delete
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
        End If

    Next shp

    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code and see if it raises the same issue.

```
Sub ClearingOfButton()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim Tmp As Variant

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    If Ws.Shapes.Count Then
        Ws.Unprotect
        Tmp = Sheets("Calculator").Range("AU64").Value

        If (Tmp = 5) Or (Tmp = 10) Or (Tmp = 19) Or (Tmp = 30) Or (Tmp = 40) Then
            For Each Shp In Sheets("Calculator").Shapes
                If Not Application.Intersect(Shp.TopLeftCell, _
                                             Ws.Range("Illustration")) Is Nothing Then
                    Shp.Delete
                End If
            Next Shp
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If it does, add the line `On Error Resume Next` before `Shp.Delete` and investigate the shape that doesn't get deleted although you expected it to.